# Trying to get an Access Token from Dwolla restful api

Tags: java, json, http, http-headers, dwolla

Im having trouble getting an access token for the sandbox environment.
Im following this guide for authenticating: [OAuth](https://developers.dwolla.com/guides/auth/client-credentials-flow.html)

So when i create my request, following this guide, i get the following response from the api:
`{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Invalid application credentials."}`

Im using key for mf client ID and secret as my client secret as per the instructions.

Here is the code Im using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/v2/token");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("client_id", "<Key>");
            conn.setRequestProperty("client_secret", "<Secret>");
            conn.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "client_credentials"); 


            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);



            System.out.println("Message:" + conn.getResponseMessage());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PaymentTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PaymentTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you generate the token within the last hour of testing your code? The [token-generator doc](http://developers.dwolla.com/resources/token-generator.html) says the short-lived access token expires one hour after it's generated.

Comment: Also, be careful not to post API private keys/secrets on public posts.

Comment: Those are keys from a sandbox but just in case i removed them. ok so im confused now, the token that gets generated when you get into the dwolla dashboard is my client secret? On the dashboard i got a "Key" and a "Secret". and a button that lets me generate a token. Ive been using "Key" as my client id. and "Secret" as my client secret

Comment: Yeah that sounds right, the ["Overview - Obtaining an application access token"](http://developers.dwolla.com/guides/auth/client-credentials-flow.html) docs, under `"Request application authorization"` and `"Request parameters"` mention the same `client_id` and `client_secret`are needed. I've not used the Dwolla API, but the authorization flow is the same as any other API and follows [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework's Steps to Authorization Code Grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1).

Comment: Those credentials you used, if they are from a sandbox may need to point to the "Sandbox API Host": `https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com`. I ran your code with the same credentials you included and got the same `"error"` that you got, which suggests we should be using a shared Sandox API endpoint for testing. If I can get sandbox access to work for me, I'll post back.

Comment: Using `https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com` thanks for that. I was able to create a customer using an access token i got from the sandbox. The problem is i cant get the access token by following the workflow, i have to get it each time from the dash bored when it expires. Maybe itl work if i use a prod client_id and client_secret but id imagine theres a way to aquire the access token in the test environment since they give u the client_id and secret in the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an access token finally. My problem is first of all the above code uses client_id and client_secret as header params. These need to go in the body of the request.

My second problem is that I used the wrong content type for the message I was sending.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
URL url = new URL("https://sandbox.dwolla.com/oauth/v2/token");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String data = "";


    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("client_id", "<Your Client ID>");
    jsonObj.put("client_secret", "<Your Client Secret>");
    jsonObj.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    data = jsonObj.toString();

    System.out.println("data = " + data);



    byte[] outputInBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write( outputInBytes );    
    os.close();


    System.out.println("Message:" + conn.getResponseMessage());


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
```